# Dynamic Querying with Google Spreedsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that i would like to query data from based on a dynamic date and time in another spreadsheet. Here is an example:

Spreadsheet A is where all of the data is located

Spreadsheet B is where we want to output data from SSA based on a date and time that is determined in SSB.

I have attempted several different formats of the =QUERY() function but I cannot figure it out. The query works but it returns empty. Please help.

Below is the spreadsheet I am working on.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ygftKJPQl6PGj0B4_5t67qvfcKw90ktj5n1JlXZaotA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=QUERY(SignUpsv2!$B$5:$Z$100, "SELECT C, D, E, Y WHERE K= DATE '"&TEXT(C1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

And if you need to query the data AND the time, entered in E1, try:

```
=QUERY(SignUpsv2!$B$5:$Z$100, "SELECT C, D, E, Y WHERE K= DATE '"&TEXT(C1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND L = '"&E1&"' ", 0)
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: Your a *bleepin* genius. Thank You